# Convert QString sprintf format to arg form

Tags: qt

Here is an example code:

```
double A = 0;
QString str;
str.sprintf("%.3f",A)
```

How to rewrite the code `str.sprintf("%.3f",A)` using the `arg` function of `QString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument a in [QString::arg(double a, int fieldWidth = 0, char format = 'g', int precision = -1, QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char(' ')) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-9) is formatted according to the specified format and precision. See [Argument Formats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats) for details.

I your example:

```
double A = 0;
QString str("%1");
str = str.arg(A,0,'f',3);
```